# How to populate ToDo list with UseEffect Axios API call in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to populate my ToDo list with all the tasks I get from my database with an API call. Unfortunately, nothing is showing up. My API call is working because the `console.log(response.data)` returns the 3 tasks in my database, but my view is not updating with the data that I got from my call. I get no errors.

```
import axios from "../axios";
import {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {ToDoFull,ToDoInner,Id,Title,Description} from "./StyledComponents.js";

const Tasks = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAllItems = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get("/tasks/all-tasks");
                if (response.data !== "") {
                    console.log(response.data); //Prints out my three objects in an array in my console. works great
                    let objects = response.data.map(JSON.stringify);
                    let uniqueSet = new Set(objects);
                    let uniqueArray = Array.from(uniqueSet).map(JSON.parse);
                    setTasks(uniqueArray);
                } else {
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        fetchAllItems();
        return () => {
            setItems([]);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <ToDoFull>
                {tasks.map((task) => {
                    <ToDoInner>
                        <ID>{task.taskid}</Title>
                        <Title>{task.title}</Title>
                        <Description>{task.description}</Description>
                    </ToDoInner>;
                })}
            </ToDoFull>
        </>
    );
};

export default Tasks;
```

Comment: If your data is in JSON Form then dont use the logic below console.log(response.data); you have written. simply use setTasks(response.data);

Comment: @AsadHaroon it is in array format not JSON. my express server sends me an array with all my task objects

Comment: Ok then remove the logic as i said above. Hope it will work fine.

Comment: And add loader state for API feedback and show loader while API is fetching your data.

Comment: I changed it to setTasks(response.data); but it still does not work. no errors though

Comment: Ohh Ok and change the code as follows:  {tasks.map((task) => {
                    return <ToDoInner>
                        <ID>{task.taskid}</Title>
                        <Title>{task.title}</Title>
                        <Description>{task.description}</Description>
                    </ToDoInner>;
                })}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide `return` inside `tasks.map()`

```
 <ToDoFull>
                {tasks.map((task) => {
                  return  (<ToDoInner>
                        <ID>{task.taskid}</Title>
                        <Title>{task.title}</Title>
                        <Description>{task.description}</Description>
                    </ToDoInner>);
                })}
            </ToDoFull>
```